# how to choose where to redirect a request depending on the validity of the token?

Tags: nginx, javascript

Is it possible to implement, and if so, how, redirecting a request to different places depending on whether the token in the request header is valid or invalid?

For example my configuration:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    js_import oauth2.js;
    js_import hello.js;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            auth_request /_oauth2_token_introspection;
            if (???) {
                js_content hello.hello_world;
            }

            if (???) {
                js_content hello.another_location;
            }
        }

        location = /_oauth2_token_introspection {
            internal;
            js_content oauth2.introspectAccessToken;
        }

        location = /auth {
            error_log /dev/stdout debug;

            internal;
            proxy_method POST;
            proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic bmdpbngtcGx1czoyNTEzOWIwZS1lNzJmLTQ0Y2ItYTU1MS04YjY5ZTFmNmIyYjE=";
            proxy_set_body "token=$http_authorization";
            proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect;
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

and oauth2.js file:

```
function introspectAccessToken(r) {
    r.subrequest("/auth",
        function(reply) {
            if (reply.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(reply.responseText);
                if (response.active == true) {
                    r.return(204);
                } else {
                    r.return(401);
                }
            } else {
                r.return(403);
            }
        }
    );
}

export default { introspectAccessToken }
```

I am now mainly interested in the internal IF, where the codes are 204 and 401. How can I implement it so that in one case the initial request goes to site1, and in the other to site2?

The request I send to nginx:

```
GET http://localhost/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: <token is here>
```

I expect that the oauth server response will contain the body:

```
{"active":false}
```

or

```
{
...
     "active": true
}
```